# How can I delete rows from a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I tried very hard to find an answer to a trivial problem: which is to delete the rows with `Complex Numbers`. I tried the following but none worked for me.

```
deneme = {{-0.01, .4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, {0.10 + 3.14 I, -0.03}, {-0.54, -0.051}, {0.03, 0.10 + 3.14 I}};
DeleteCases[deneme, {I ..}]
DeleteCases[deneme, {Complex ..}]
Cases[deneme, Cases[deneme, Except@{Complex ..}]]
Pick[deneme, Unitize[Abs[deneme].ConstantArray[1., 2]], 1]
```

I wonder why it is so difficult to find an answer to this problem.

Comment: `Select[deneme, VectorQ[#, Element[#, Reals] &] &]`

Comment: @Alan No need `VectorQ`   This is just fine `Select[deneme, Element[#, Reals] &]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[deneme, {___, _Complex, ___}]
```

> {{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}

```
Select[FreeQ[_Complex]] @ deneme
```

> {{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}

```
Cases[_?(FreeQ[_Complex])]@deneme
```

> {{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{-0.01, .4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, 
   {0.10 + 3.14 I, -0.03}, {-0.54, -0.051}, {0.03, 0.10 + 3.14 I}};
```

Using `RealValuedNumberQ` (new in 13.3)

```
Cases[{__?RealValuedNumberQ}] @ list
```

{{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{-0.01, .4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07}, {-1.55, -0.08}, 
        {0.10 + 3.14  I, -0.03}, {-0.54, -0.051}, {0.03, 0.10 + 3.14  I}};
```

Using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, VectorQ[#, RealValuedNumericQ] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07},{-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}*)
```

Or using `Delete` and `Position`:

```
Delete[#, Position[#, {OrderlessPatternSequence[_Complex, _]}]] &@list

(*{{-0.01, 0.4}, {-0.47, -0.054}, {-0.82, -0.07},{-1.55, -0.08}, {-0.54, -0.051}}*)
```